# Syntax error in sybase iq dynamic query

Tags: t-sql, sybase

I am new to Sybase IQ and when I try to execute this code, an error is displayed

> Could not execute the statement. Syntax error near SELECT on line 1

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(500)

SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM SNP_CHECK_TAB A INNER JOIN SELECT * FROM E$_auditemp_trg B ON B.ODI_ORIGIN = A.ORIGIN WHERE B.ODI_SESS_NO =532001 ORDER BY B.ODI_CHECK_DATE DESC'

EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

Please help me fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the sql in your query editor (either you need parenthesis around the second `select *`, or it shouldn't be there...)

Comment: Hi , i want to join those two tables ,if  I put parenthesis  around second query ,it gives synatx error near 'ON'error.code is below:DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(500)
SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM SNP_CHECK_TAB A INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM E$_auditemp_trg B ON B.ODI_ORIGIN = A.ORIGIN WHERE B.ODI_SESS_NO =532001 ORDER BY B.ODI_CHECK_DATE DESC)'
EXECUTE(@SQL)

Comment: You seem to be confused about join syntax... (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

Comment: Hi ,I have modified the query to:DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(500)
Set @SQL='SELECT * FROM SNP_CHECK_TAB A INNER JOIN E$_auditemp_trg B ON B.ODI_ORIGIN = A.ORIGIN WHERE B.ODI_SESS_NO =532001 ORDER BY B.ODI_CHECK_DATE DESC'
EXECUTE(@SQL) ,but getting error "result set not permitted in batch statement"

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `parenthesis`  around second query for `Inner Join`.

You Have to use like

```
... INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM E$_auditemp_trg ) B ...
                                           -- ^ you need to enclose here
```

Instaed of

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM E$_auditemp_trg B ON B.ODI_ORIGIN = A.ORIGIN WHERE
B.ODI_SESS_NO =532001 ORDER BY B.ODI_CHECK_DATE DESC)
                                                 -- ^ (not here)
```

Try like this

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(500)
SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM SNP_CHECK_TAB A INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM E$_auditemp_trg) B ON B.ODI_ORIGIN = A.ORIGIN WHERE B.ODI_SESS_NO =532001 ORDER BY B.ODI_CHECK_DATE DESC'
EXECUTE(@SQL)
```

Comment: Hi getting below error:"result set not permitted in <batch statement>

Comment: @user3807245 You attempted to execute a SELECT statement in a context where a result set is not permitted.

Comment: any suggestion on how the query can be modified to get the expected result?